# $(.class).empty always missing one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

`enter code here`I am having a little problem with jquery.empty().
I have some Html Divs which look like below:

```
<div id="Description_Error" class="ui-helper-hidden errorMessage"></div>
    <div id="Order_Error" class="ui-helper-hidden errorMessage"></div>
    <div id="ColorHex_Error" class="ui-helper-hidden errorMessage"></div>
```

These Divs get filled up at run time with some Uls and Lis. They are basically used to show the errors. Now I am wiping out all the errors that it was showing before I do  a POST.

I use

$('ui-helper-hidden errorMessage').empty();

for that. Now, i fit is showing all three errors then it will wipe out two bue leave one. If it is showing only one error at the time then it will not be removed at all. I am not sure why class selection decides to leave one element behind all the times. Anyway, i tried to replicate the same behavior on Jsfiddler but it works fine. I am not able to find a clue on what might be wrong on my code. Any suggestions?

here is the fiddler link which works all file. Just my HTMl code does not work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/g55Rs/3/

Comment: Remove the space. `$('.ui-helper-hidden.errorMessage').empty();`

Comment: Those would be two classes, not one with a space?

Comment: Make certain the div that is being left behind has correct spelling and matches the class selector exactly.

Comment: Well, I changed class name to something simple 'xyz' and same behavior. Now the element which is left behind is same class selector. Actually, it is not the same element all the times. whichever is first is missed. For example if it is showing `Description_Error` and `ColorHex_Error` one after another then it will miss `Description_Error` but if I reverse the order then other one will be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are neither refering to a class nore an element identifier.

```
$('ui-helper-hidden errorMessage').empty();
```

To reference classes use the `.` and to use element identifiers use `#`.

In your case this will empty all the divs:

```
// Selecting all elements which have both classes
$('.ui-helper-hidden.errorMessage').empty();
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/znbMZ/) - Empty all element which have both classes

I also added some element which only have one or the other class in the DEMO to show that they are not effected.

Comment: I am sorry for being hast in my question but in my code I am using `.` but it is not helping.

Comment: @Californicated: Can you add the actual script are using to your post and make sure the rendered HTML is the one you posted. It just seems odd that, given the HTML you posted, the selector doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry. I was so wrong. Yes,  your two class example works and makes sense. I should had just worked with one class at a time and that should had taken care of my issue easily. Thanks :).